# Unity C# Script Moving a character 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting

I'm trying to make a script to control the character. I want the character to move a certain distance to the right while alternating LEFT ARROW and then RIGHT ARROW inputs. So ideally when i start the game, I press RIGHT ARROW - the character moves right say 10px, then press LEFT ARROW - the character moves right and this pattern continues on alternating and never allowing two of the same inputs after eachother eg: LEFT ARROW LEFT ARROW or RIGHT ARROW RIGHT ARROW.

Comment: Consider adding what you have tried yet

Answer (score 3):

Ended up going for this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

    public float moveSpeed;
    public float jumpHeight;
    private KeyCode lastHitKey;

    void Start()
    {
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space))
        {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(0, jumpHeight);
        }


        if(Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.D))
        {
            if(lastHitKey == KeyCode.D)
            {

            }else
            {
                GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(moveSpeed, 0);
                lastHitKey = KeyCode.D;
            }
        }


        if(Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.A))
        {
            if(lastHitKey == KeyCode.A)
            {

            }else
            {
                GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(moveSpeed, 0);
                lastHitKey = KeyCode.A;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using "KeyCode.A" in an if statement you could write:

```
if(GetComponent<RigidBody2D>().velocity.x < maxSpeed){
    GetComponent<RigidBody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * speedMult, 0));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One quick solution (probably not the best) would be to declare 2 booleans, lets say boolean right,left and set them to false.
In the events after a key is pressed , lets say for the right key:

```
{
    right=true;
    if(left==true)
        //move character
    left=false;
}
```

and for the left key would be

```
 {
    left=true;
    if(right==true)
        //move character
    right=false;
}
```

this way, the character won't move unless the right and left arrows alternated.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing to do is changing move speed from positive to negative number for example from 10 to -10

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2((moveSpeed - moveSpeed * 2), 0);
    }
```